# Generics (and Wildcards) in Java

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, wildcard

A book I am reading on Java tells me that the following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)

public void takeThing(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list);
```

On the opposite page, I am informed that the latter piece of code uses the '?' as a wildcard, meaning that nothing can be added to the list.

Does this mean that if I ever have a list (or other collection types?) that I can't make them simultaneously accept polymorphic arguments AND be re-sizable? Or have I simply misunderstood something?

All help/comments appreciated, even if they go slightly off topic. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing can be added to list in either case because you didn't specify the lower bound.

Comment: Its only the case with `extends`. If you use `super`, you can add elements to that list. But in that case, you can pass a list of super types only.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: in the first case, you could do `T t = list.get(0); list.add(t);` for example, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @JBNizet Heh heh, good point, if that is of any use :)

Comment: Technically you can add `null` in both cases.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Something can be added in either case. `null` for one, but one can also add duplicates of possibly existing elements. To do that for the second case one merely has to capture the wildcard. I'm constantly amazed at the lack of awareness when it comes to wildcard capture.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik What is 'the lower bound'?

Comment: @RohitJain So would it be the following? public void takeThing(ArrayList<? super Animal> list);

Comment: @BenSchulz How would "capturing the wildcard" work?

Comment: Note: It's recommended to implement against interfaces not implementations where possible. In this case: use List instead of ArrayList where possible.

Comment: @Jesper You could call the first method from the second method (assuming they do not clash). That would capture the wildcard as `T`.

Comment: @ConorW.. Yeah, but in that case, you can't pass a `List<Dog>` into that.

Comment: @BenSchulz As far as awareness, are you aware that you have just diluted others' short and concise points, topping it off with an irrelevant personal note?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I suppose I could have refreshed the page before posting, but when I loaded it those comments were not yet written. Either way, none of the comments mentioned wildcard capture. As for personal notes: I'm sorry if you're embarrassed by your ignorance. ;)

Comment: @BenSchulz Yes, you'd be right, I am ignorant as to what you think you are achieving by flailing around that term. More correctly, I have three or four ideas on what one **could** mean by that, none of them making much sense in the context of my initial comment.

Comment: @JBNizet: however, the second method can simply call the first method directly with its argument, so it can do anything that the first method can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean that if I ever have a list (or other collection types?) that I can't make them simultaneously accept polymorphic arguments AND be re-sizable?

No.

The two pieces of code are not *completely* equivalent. In the first line, the method `takeThing` has a type parameter `T`. In the second line, you're using a wildcard.

When you would use the first version, you would specify what concrete type would be used for `T`. Because the concrete type is then known, there's no problem to add to the list.

In the second version, you're just saying "`list` is an `ArrayList` that contains objects of some unknown type that extends `Animal`". What exactly that type is, isn't known. You can't add objects to such a list because the compiler doesn't have enough information (it doesn't know what the actual type is) to check if what you're adding to the list should be allowed.

Comment: Notice `<T extends Animal>` in the declaration of first method. We can't add a new value in that list. If of course the new value is not null.

Comment: @RohitJain But that's by itself not a reason why you can't add anything to the list. The problem would be where you'd get the `T` object from to add to the list.

Comment: For example, this works without a problem: `public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list, T e) { list.add(e); }`

Comment: Or this (thanks to Ben's tip): `public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list) { list.add(list.get(0)); }`

Comment: @Jesper.. Yeah that would work, because now we have explicitly adding the same type of element, that is used in the list. In that case your point is valid.

Comment: @Jesper.. But if you are adding a new element created inside that method, then well, you won't be able to add.

Comment: @Jesper.. Yeah, because we can't declare a variable with wildcard. So there is where exists the difference. :) Nice catch :)

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, that's what I meant with what I wrote before: the problem is then: how can you create a new `T`?

Comment: @Jesper.. I have to give +1 for your answer. Its perfect. :)

Comment: "When you would use the first version, you would specify what concrete type would be used for T. Because the concrete type is then known, there's no problem to add to the list." This doesn't make sense. The chosen type argument is only known in the caller's scope. But when you're talking about adding to the list, that's inside the function, so you don't know what T is, and it could be anything.

Comment: @Jesper: As for your comments, the first code example doesn't apply, because it changes the question. (Of course if you have *two* uses of T, they cannot be eliminated because they form a constraint. But the point is that when T is used only in one place, it often is unnecessary.) And about the second one, yes, but the wildcard version can still *accomplish* the same thing, by simply calling the non-wildcard version with its argument, so they are equivalent in what they can take and what they can ultimately do.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if adding to a list is involved inside a method that accepts just the list  without the thing to add, you'll have somewhere else something that is an `Animal` and you'll want to add it to the list. In this case your method must be declared so that all the list types it accepts allow adding an `Animal` into them. This will have to be a `List<Animal>` or a list of some **supertype** of `Animal`. It can't possibly be a `List<Dog>`— the element you are adding could be any `Animal`.

This is where the concept of the *lower bound*, and the keyword `super`, come in. The type declaration `List<? super Animal>` matches all the acceptable types as described above. On the other hand, you won't be able to **get** elements out of such a list in a typesafe way because they can in general be of **any type at all**. If a method wants to both add and get elements of declared type `Animal`, the only valid type it can accept is a `List<Animal>`.