# When to use wildcards in Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

this is from **HeadFirst Java**: ( page 575 )

This:

```
public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)
```

Does the same thing as this:

```
public void takeThing(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list)
```

So here is my question: if they are exactly same, why don't we write

```
public <? extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<?> list)
```

or

```
public void takeThing(ArrayList<T extends Animal> list)
```

Also, when would it be useful to use a ? instead of a T in a method declaration ( as above ) with Generics, or for a Class declaration? What are the benefits?

Comment: How can you say `public <? extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<?> list)`? if you say void then there is no return type. if you specify then there is a return type. i didn't know that you can specify to have return type or no return type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474791/generics-and-wildcards-in-java?rq=1 This is for future reference whoever sees this question!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The big difference between

```
public <T extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<T> list)
```

and

```
public void takeThing(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list)
```

is that in the former method you can refer to "T" within the method as the concrete class that was given. In the second method you cannot do this.

Here a more complex example to illustrate this:

```
// here i can return the concrete type that was passed in
public <T extends Animal> Map<T, String> getNamesMap(ArrayList<T> list) {
    Map<T, String> names = new HashMap<T, String>();
    for (T animal : list) {
        names.put(animal, animal.getName()); // I assume there is a getName() method
    }
    return names;
}

// here i have to use general Animal
public Map<Animal, String> getNamesMap(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list) {
    Map<Animal, String> names = new HashMap<Animal, String>();
    for (Animal animal : list) {
        names.put(animal, animal.getName()); // I assume there is a getName() method
    }
    return names;
}
```

With the first method if you pass in an List of Cats you get a Map with Cat as key. The second method would always return a Map with general Animal key.

By the way this is not valid java syntax:

```
public <? extends Animal> void takeThing(ArrayList<?> list)
```

Using this form of generic method declaration you have to use a valid java identifier and not "?".

Edit:

The form "? extends Type" only applies to variable or parameter type declaration. Within a generic method declration it has to be "Identifier extends Type" as you are able to refer to the "Identifier" from within your method.

Comment: The big difference is not that you can not refer to ? as a type. If that were the only thing ? is good for, then it would be completely useless.

Comment: @bennidi: What big differences do you see else in the case of a method declaration? You can give the same parameters in both cases. The generic method declaration gives you the benefit of refering to the type which enables higher type safty (which is definitly not useless).

Comment: Type safety is what you get when you use an identifier and refer to that within you method signature. I didn't say that this was useless. I said that "?" would be useless if its only capabilities were just to not be referable in the rest of the method. The big difference is that you can't add anything to List<? extends Animal>. Please, See me answer below.

Comment: I think you're on the right track, but you're creating a strawman by returning something that includes `T`.  The example in the question is a `void` method.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I only did this example to show that T can be used inside the method. It was only an example not directly related to the example in the question (as he asked for differences and usages).

Comment: Yes but you are talking about a different example. With the original example, what is the need to refer to `T` inside the method?

Comment: For the example in the question there are no need. But the question asked "Also, when would it be useful to use a ? instead of a T in a method declaration ( as above ) with Generics, or for a Class declaration? What are the benefits?" and i gave an example.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, but why would I ever want to use ?. Can you give an example for that as well?

Comment: This is actually a good question. Personally i tend to always use the "Identifier extends Type" form as it has more possibilities and allows the same parameter types. Maybe someone else could give a hint why to prefer the ? syntax.

Answer (score 14):

Wild cards are about co/contra variance of generics. I will try to make clear what this means by providing some examples.

Basically it is related to the fact that for types S and T, where S is a subtype of T, a generic type `G<S>` is not a valid subtype of `G<T>`

```
List<Number> someNumbers = new ArrayList<Long>(); // compile error
```

You can remedy this with wild cards

```
List<? extends Number> someNumbers = new ArrayList<Long>(); // this works
```

Please note, that you can not put anything into such a list

```
someNumbers.add(2L); //compile error
```

even (and more surprising for many developers):

```
List<? extends Long> someLongs = new ArrayList<Long>();
someLongs.add(2L); // compile error !!!
```

I think SO is not the right place to discuss that in detail. I will try to find some of the articles and papers that explain this in more detail.

Comment: By the way: Ceylon has a very nice way to deal with those specialties of type systems.

Comment: the question is about parameters to a method

Comment: This is the only question on the board that actually answers the question.  The others only say that bounded types are superior to wildcards.

Comment: Thanks @Rap. Co and contra variance are not broadly understood and seem to continuously confuse people (including myself). I think Java's type system also doesn't offer the best solution. Ceylon or Scala for example offer much more mechanisms to handle generic polymorphism. BTW, upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 7):

Binding the type to a type parameter can be more powerful, depending on what the method is supposed to do.  I'm not sure what `takeThing` is supposed to do, but imagine in general we have a method with one of these type signatures:

```
public <T extends Animal> void foo(ArrayList<T> list);

//or

public void foo(ArrayList<? extends Animal> list);
```

Here's a concrete example of something you can only do with the **first** type signature:

```
public <T extends Animal> void foo(ArrayList<T> list) {
    list.add(list.remove(0)); // (cycle front element to the back)
}
```

In this case `T` is required to inform the type checker that the element being *removed* from the list is an OK element to *add* to the list.

You could not do this with a wildcard because, as the wildcard has not been bound to a type parameter, its context is not tracked (well, it is tracked, through "captures", but it's not available to leverage).  You can get more information on this in another answer I've given: [How do generics of generics work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16449799/how-do-generics-of-generics-work/16451216#16451216)

Comment: "of something you can only do with the first type signature" Not true. I can have a method of the second signature call the method of the first signature. Then, to any outside code, they "do" the same task.

Comment: @newacct: Ok, that's a bit nitpicky.  You still need the type parameter, just not externally visible.  In the post I cite, I go into  detail about how a helper generic method can help you "unleash" the wildcard capture.  Doing that in this case just needlessly complicates things for no perceivable advantage.

Comment: Suppose you are writing an API. You would always use the second signature. Whether you internally use another method with the first signature is an implementation detail that should not be revealed to the outside. The point is, in this case, the type parameter serves no purpose in enforcing any constraints to the caller, since it is only used in one place in parameters. Its purpose happens to be completely internal. So it should be kept internal. Tomorrow you might change the method so that the parameter is no longer needed; the method signature shouldn't have to change.

Comment: @newacct: I don't disagree, but you're downvoting me as if the question was about the best approach for choosing an API signature, when the question was about what functionality one provides over the other.  My main point is still exactly correct.  Though you might introduce a level of indirection and hide it internally, you still admit that eventually you need a method with the first signature as I've mentioned.  You can't do the job with only the second signature.

Answer (score 5):

If you write `? extends T` you say "anything that is a T or more specific". For example: a `List<Shape>` can have only `Shape`s in it, while a `List<? extends Shape>` can have `Shape`s, `Circle`s, `Rectangle`s, etc.

If you write `? super T` you say "anything that is a T or more general". This is less often used, but has it's use cases. A typical example would be a callback: if you want to pass a `Rectangle` back to a callback, you can use `Callback<? super Rectangle>`, since a `Callback<Shape>` will be able to handle `Rectangle`s as well.

Here's [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: You don't need wild cards to say "anything that is T or subtype". You can simply say S extends T. Wild cards are necessary to make generics support co/contra variance.

Comment: One rule of thumb is that you use "super" with incoming types (method parameters) and "extends" with outgoing (return types)

Comment: @KorayTugay: I didn't really get your question due to the original formatting problem. I thought I give it a shot anyway.

Comment: @bennidi: I was using this in the context of creating lists, so we are talking about covariance.

Answer (score 1):

If your `takeThing` method needs to add elements to the `list` parameter, the wildcard version will not compile.

The interesting case is when you are not adding to the list and both versions seem to compile and work.

In this case, you would write the wildcard version when you want to allow different type of animals in the list (more flexibility) and the parameter version when you require a fixed type of animal in the list: the T type.

For example the `java.util.Collection` declares:

```
interface Collection<E> {
  ...
  public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);
  ...
}
```

And suppose you have the following code:

```
Collection<Object> c = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, 2); 
Collection<Integer> i = Arrays.<Integer>asList(1, 2, 3); 
i.containsAll(c); //compiles and return true as expected
```

If the `java.util.Collection` would be:

```
interface Collection<E> {
    ...
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<E> c);
    ...
}
```

The above test code would not compile and the flexibility of the `Collection` API would be reduced.

It worth noting that the latter definition of `containsAll` has the advantage of catching more errors at compile time, for example:

```
Collection<String> c = Arrays.asList("1", "2"); 
Collection<Integer> i = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3); 
i.containsAll(c); //does not compile, the integer collection can't contain strings
```

But misses the valid test with a `Collection<Object> c = Arrays.<Object>asList(1, 2);`

Comment: "If your takeThing method needs to add elements to the list parameter, the wildcard version will not compile." But where are you going to find a `T` to add to it anyway?

Comment: @newacct You might try to add via an `Animal` or `Animal` subclass reference.

Comment: but then it won't be a `T`

Comment: It does not even compile. @dcernahoschi

Answer (score 1):

Java Generics Wildcards usage is governed by the GET-PUT Principle (Which is also known as the IN-OUT principle). This states that:
**Use an "extends" wildcard when you only get values out of a structure, Use a "super" wildcard when you only put values into a structure, and do not use wildcards when you do both.**  This does not apply to a method's return type. **Do not use a wildcard as a return type**. See example below:

```
public static<T> void copyContainerDataValues(Container<? extends T> source, Container<? super T> destinationtion){
destination.put(source.get());
}
```

Comment: Rahul, I think your response is _perfect..._ for a different question. Perhaps if the question had been "When to use _extends_ vs _super_ when using wildcards", I've would voted for your answer. And no, I'm not being sarcastic, I actually liked your explanation because I'm trying to learn generics, and that part of wildcards was a little confusing until your answer came up.