# Optional<> and return type narrowing

Tags: java, option-type, narrowing

In Java < 8, returning "unsafe" objects (objects or null), I was able to specialize return type in subclass:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
interface Sup { A a(); /* returns A instance, or null */ }
interface Sub extends Sup { B a(); }
```

In Java 8, if I want to make my API "safer", I should return `Optional<A>` instead of "raw" `A`:

```
interface Sup { Optional<A> a(); }
interface Sub extends Sup { Optional<B> a(); }
```

But doesn't compile! Because `Optional<B>` is not a subclass of `Optional<A>`.

How I'm supposed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use wildcards.

```
interface Sup { Optional<? extends A> a(); }

interface Sub extends Sup { Optional<? extends B> a(); }
```

I could have made it just `Optional<B>` but using `Optional<? extends B>` allows another interface to extend `Sub` and do the same thing.

Personally, I think this is a bit of a mess, and it would be preferable to just return `A` or `B`, or `null` where necessary.

Comment: There are [schools of thought](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9561295/1079354) which believe that shifting to the `Optional` paradigm produces fewer NPEs, and forces one to reason better about what behaviors the code actually has.

Comment: @Makoto I know the arguments, and I agree with them (I use `Optional` all the time). My comment at the end was about combining `?` and `Optional`

Comment: Using the  upper bound isn't the worst thing that could happen; there may be very justifiable reasons as to why one would do that.  The reason I reacted the way I did was because you had mentioned `null`.

Comment: @Makoto You never return `null`?

Comment: While I think that this is getting a bit too chatty, I don't return `null` where I can help it - where I have access to use `Optional`, either with Guava or with Java 8, I elect to use this pattern instead of `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your parent bounds to use wildcards:

```
Optional<? extends A> // parent
Optional<? extends B> // child
```

The reason that your code doesn't work now is due to the fact that generics are invariant.  `B` is-an `A`, but `Optional<B>` is not an `Optional<A>`.