# What's difference between these generic methods?

Tags: java, generics

What's difference between these?

```
public <T extends MyClass> void myMethod (ArrayList<T> list) {
}
```

---

```
public void myMethod (ArrayList<? extends MyClass> list) {
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707340/when-to-use-wildcards-in-java-generics

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `<T extends MyClass>`

   - Denotes a **specific** sub-type of `MyClass`, called `T`.
   - You can actually *refer* to the type `T` within the method implementation. For example, you can assign elements from the list to new variables of type `T`.
   - You can both add and remove elements from the list.
2. `<? extends MyClass>`

   - Denotes a **whole family of sub-types** of `MyClass`. The exact substitute is *unknown* at compile-time and thus, cannot be referred, nor new variables of this very type can be introduced.
   - You cannot add new elements to the list (because the actual type is unknown)
   - You can only get elements from the list. They, however, can be only assigned to variables of type `MyClass`. Additional down-casting may be needed for some specific sub-types of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you can refer to `T` as being the type of the MyClass or sub-class.

In the second case `T` can be what ever you have defined outside this method (or nothing if you don't have a type called T)