# Java Generics and Wildcard

Tags: java

if I change

```
Team<FootballPlayer> adelaideCrows = new Team<>("Adelaide Crows");
```

to

```
Team<FootballPlayer> adelaideCrows = new Team("Adelaide Crows");
```

Would it be wrong or will I get any error later?
And why ? wildcard cannot use at class level? like

```
public class B <? extends A>
```

Comment: Have you *tried*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use generic methods and when to use wild-card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176594/when-to-use-generic-methods-and-when-to-use-wild-card)

Comment: You're instantiating a raw type there. The compiler will let you do this, for compatibility with legacy code, but you shouldn't. If a constructor or method calls for type parameters, you should provide them (or allow the compiler to infer them using the diamond operator, per the first example).

Comment: Also read; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707340/when-to-use-wildcards-in-java-generics