# Java Generics not able to add child to List of parent

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, wildcard

Why the below code is showing a compilation error. Doesn't extend mean it can take any subclass of `Number`, Also compilation is shown in the `add` method not while defining the `List` if it doesn't support this construct it should show compilation error while declaring.

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1)
```

Comment: `? extends Number` means that collection is `read-only`

Comment: This wild card allows you can assign a collection of type `Number` or its subtype. That's why `List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();` compiles correctly.

Comment: But you cant add anything such a list `List<? extends Number>` because this variable can be assigned to a `List<Double>` or `List<Byte>` which are not compatible with Integer. This list is `read-only`

Comment: so basically there's no use of such direct instantiation unless used as method arguments.

Comment: Exactly, a wild-card-collection will be useless if it'll be assigned with a newly created empty collection. But it's powerful as an argument of a method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933447/how-do-you-cast-a-list-of-supertypes-to-a-list-of-subtypes pls check the answer by @Salandur, so misleading, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: the reference you've provided is related to casting will generics

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707340/when-to-use-wildcards-in-java-generics

Comment: If you see the answer by @R-tooR using `super` it works, I am more confused now :P

Answer (score 0):

Number literals are of type int. Using construction `<? extends Number>` you ensure, that you can pass only instances of `Number` class, or any classes, that `Number` inherits from (that is `java.lang.Object`). If you want to add subtypes of `Number` class, e.g. `Integers` you should use `<? super Number>` (it means: for whose `Number` is a super class)
You may want to use:

```
List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1); //no compile-time error
```

However, if you want to use elements of the collection, you may use them as instances of classes that extends `Number` class.

```
    List<? super Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    print(list);

    List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
    objs.add(1);
    print(objs);

    List<Number> nums = new ArrayList<>();
    nums.add(1);
    print(nums);
}

public static void print(List<? super Number> list){ // you can pass List of instances of type Number or upper
    for(Object num: list){ // but you have to refer to them as Objects (it is an upper class of Number
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```